# How is navigation stack and launch modes handled in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I wish to know for how to navigate between screen in Flutter by meeting all requirements that may come during application development. For example normal navigation to next page is easy but I want to play with stack. 
1.How to  clear stack when login completed so that from home page when user does the back press he finishes the application.
2. How to sign out from my app that is when I press sign out all pages are cleared from the stack and login page appears, and if press back then the app finishes.

Right now if anyone can provide an example or explanation for only above two then that will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For both of your cases you can use [`pushAndRemoveUntil`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html).

Case 1, i.e. you remove all routes (login routes) and navigate to your normal screen:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(yourHomeScreenRoute, (Route<dynamic> route) => false)
```

The expression `(Route<dynamic> route) => false` will just always return false, i.e. remove all routes.

Case 2, i.e. you remove all routes again and navigate to your login screen.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(yourLoginScreenRoute, (Route<dynamic> route) => false)
```

Another method is just [`popUntil`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html), although I think that my concept will satisfy you.

In case you do not know how you would create routes, check [this link](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/).

Comment: Thats a good solution but what if I want to finish the application on back press. How will I implement that? because in my case wen I press back it goes to the previous page.

Comment: @AnkitShukla My answer solves that problem.because there will not be a "previous page".

Comment: Yeah right, I figured that out after little trials.